# Spring - HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource is not available

Tags: spring

I have the 404 error when requesting a page. I have a users page with a list of objects that the user can click on to then carry out a number of transactions, add, edit etc.

The controller for it

```
     @RequestMapping(value="/main/user/setter/addpage/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String getAddPage(@RequestParam("userId") Integer userId, ModelMap model) {

     Module module = new Module(); 
     model.addAttribute("userId", userId);
     model.addAttribute("module", module);
    return "/main/user/setter/addpage";

  }
```

The page I want to get

```
 <c:url var="processUrl" value="/main/user/setter/addpage/?id=${userId}" />
 <form:form modelAttribute="module" method="POST" action="${processUrl}" name="module" 

 enctype="multipart/form-data">
 </form:form>
```

The page that I'm requesting it from:

```
   <c:forEach items="${users}" var="setter" >
   <c:url var="addUrl" value="/main/user/setter/addpage?userId=${setter.userId}" />
    <td>
   <a href="${addUrl}" class="button round colour right add text-upper">add</a>
   </td>
```

When I click on the add link above it goes to the 404 page. Obviously the url is going through. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/main/user/setter/addpage"
```

instead of

```
@RequestMapping(value="/main/user/setter/addpage/"
```